# How we can add JPagination in Joomla 1.5 module.?

Tags: joomla

I am developing my own custom module as per my requirement with MVC architecture.Now i want to use Joomla Pagination. please help how i can use this in my single file module.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should specify whether you want to use pagination from an already existing component or create it inside your module from scratch

Comment: I want to create pagination inside my module using Jpagination..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JPagination

http://docs.joomla.org/Using_JPagination_in_your_component